# Loop Through Columns JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have managed to write some javascript code to loop through three columns and display the specific HTML elements. It loops through the first column and then stops. I can't seem to get it to change the counter variable to change columns. Please find below the code I am using.

```js
window.onload = function load() {
  var counter = 1;
  var id = "col" + counter;
  var skills = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("p");
  var progress = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (i = 0; i < progress.length; i++) {
    console.log(counter);
    console.log(skills.length);
    if (i < skills.length) {
      counter++;
    }
    console.log(i);
    alert("Skill: " + skills[i].innerHTML + "; " + "Progress: " + progress[i].innerHTML)
  }

  document.getElementById("skills").innerHTML = skills[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = progress[0].innerHTML;
}
```

```css
.resume {
  width: 816px;
  margin: 48px 48px 48px 48px;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 16px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 4px;
}

.header hr {
  margin: 5px;
}

.name {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.contact p {
  margin: 10px;
}

.summary h2,
.skills h2,
.professionalhistory h2,
.education h2 {
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.skills {
  line-height: 13px;
}

.skills p {
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #BCBEBF;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 13px;
  margin: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #323232;
  text-align: left;
  line-height: 13px;
  padding: 1px 10px 2px;
}

.progress-bar span {
  padding: 1px 10px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

.employer {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.position {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.description {
  width: 95%;
  margin-left: 12px;
}

.results {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.titles {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Home | Resume</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="js/jsTest.js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/55fed2cea8.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="resume">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="header">
            <h1 class="name">Troy Andrew Pilewski</h1>
            <hr />
            <div class="contact">
            </div>
            <hr />
            <hr />
          </div>
          <div class="skills">
            <h2>Possesses Advance Knowledge Of</h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div id="col1" class="col-lg-4">
                <p>Microsoft Operating Systems</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Microsoft Office SharePoint Services</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:53.85%">
                    <span>7 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Microsoft Active Directory</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Microsoft Exchange Services</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Microsoft Office Suite</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Cisco Networking Devices</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>VMWare Products</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="col2" class="col-lg-4">
                <p>Project Management</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:38.46%">
                    <span>5 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Personnel Management</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Training and Development</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Customer Service Relations</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:61.54%">
                    <span>8 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Performance Management</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Oral Expressive</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Critical Thinker</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="col3" class="col-lg-4">
                <p>Complex Problem Solver</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Attention to Detail</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:100.00%">
                    <span>13 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Sandler Sales Concepts</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:23.08%">
                    <span>3 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Visual Basic for Applications</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:69.23%">
                    <span>9 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Java Application Development</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:7.69%">
                    <span>1 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Microsoft Visual Studio</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:84.62%">
                    <span>11 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <p>Microsoft SharePoint Designer</p>
                <div class="progress">
                  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="13" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="13" style="width:38.46%">
                    <span>5 Years</span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you have a single loop, that seems to loop through a column ... you have no other loop, so not sure how you think it would do what you expect

Comment: however, the code you've got will process **all** spans, regardless of which column they are in - probably not what you wanted to do

Comment: I think I miss wrote the if statement. It should change the counter if when it reaches the end of the column.

Comment: irrelevant, you still need two loops

Comment: I don't understand why you would need multiple loops if you could change the counter and continue one.

Comment: I don't see any columns, just get a bunch of alerts then some console errors. Try posting a **minimal** example that displays the issue.

Comment: yeah, you could do it with a single loop ... more complicated that way though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect to see a nested loop for what you claim you want to do ... basically, something like this

```
window.onload = function load() {
    for(col = 1; col <= 3; col++) {
        var id = "col" + col;
        var contain = document.getElementById(id);
        // get skills inside the current "contain" (column)
        var skills = contain.getElementsByTagName("p");
        // get progress inside the current "contain" (column)
        var progress = contain.getElementsByTagName("span");
        for (i = 0; i < progress.length; i++) {
            // do things for each span in a column here
        }
        // do things for each column
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try the above script tonight.

Comment: Please find a fiddle which displays what I was trying to do. Not sure why in the fiddle the progress bars don't increase to the correct position.[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KhmerBoi1/c3xto4kh/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try my change below with nested for-loop; all I modified was the javascript.

```
window.onload = function load() {
  var counter = 1;

  var progress = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (i = 0; i < progress.length; i++) {
    var id = "col" + (i+1);
    var skills = document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName("p");
    for(j = 0; j < skills.length; j++)
      alert("Skill: " + skills[j].innerHTML + "; " + "Progress: " + progress[i].innerHTML)
  }    
  document.getElementById("skills").innerHTML = skills[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = progress[0].innerHTML;
}
```